# How do i fire an event after a few seconds?

Tags: c#, events, methods, timer

I am making a application where i would like to log in with a face detection. But this is not real, its just to make ik look like its scanning. 
So when i press the LOG IN button, the kinect takes my picture and show me the picture, on top of it is showing me in a text that its scanning.
Now i am stuck with the following issue, when i press the login button, the scanning label appears, but i would like to fire an other event that takes me to the next page, the homepage.
So i want the SCANNING label appearing for 3 seconds, and then the page should change.
This is what i tried, i worked with a timer, but that doesnt do annything.

```
    private void ActionButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        _main.TakePicture();
        identifyBox.Source = _main.source.Clone();
        scanningLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        _storyboard = (Storyboard)FindResource("scanningSB");
        //_storyboard.Begin();
        Start();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _tm = new Timer(3000);
        _tm.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_tm_Elapsed);
        _tm.Enabled = true;
    }

    void _tm_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_tm == new Timer(3000))
        {
             ((Timer)sender).Enabled = false; 
            _main.ContentPage.Children.Clear();
            _main.ContentPage.Children.Add(_homeScreen);
        }
    }
```

Okay i removed the if statement, but now it fires every 3 seconds a method.
How can i make it work 1 time.

Ok even this works, now i my ContentPage wont change? It gives me this error: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. 
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can remove condition

```
if (_tm == new Timer(3000))
```

and keep it simple

```
void _tm_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{

    ((Timer)sender).Enabled = false; 

    _main.ContentPage.Children.Clear();
    _main.ContentPage.Children.Add(_homeScreen);

}
```

when you set `_tm = new Timer(3000);` it will set the time to fire event after 3 seconds..

Comment: I just want it 1 time to fire after 3 sec. It keeps on firing after every 3 seconds?

Comment: my sender does not contain an Enabled property?

Comment: if its `Timer`, it should have `Enabled` property as you have used inside `Start` method..  `_tm.Enabled = true;` try casting the sender as Timer..

Comment: `_tm.Enabled = false;` won't work inside the Elapsed handler.. as `_tm` is unknown.. you have to use `sender` itself..

Comment: I tried it like this,    Timer tm = (Timer) sender;
            tm.Enabled = false; but it still fires every 3 seconds.

Comment: updated again..you can use the exact code I have given. make sure, that particular statement is executed.

Comment: you can use `((Timer)sender).Stop();` also

Comment: oh dear, i have another problem regarding the timer, it tells me that: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. because of the _main.ContentPage.Children.Clear(); Do u have any idea ?

Comment: @Letoir: that was causing error and timer was not being disabled earlier.. by the way what is `_main`? and this problem is not regarding timer.. You have to post a separate question for this

Comment: _main, is my MainWindow.Xaml.cs , are u sure its not regarding timer, because when i use this _main.ContentPage.Children.Clear(); in the ActionButton_click it works perfectly. In the tm_Elapsed it doesnt work. I have read somewhere about a dispatchtimer. Does the timer create a new thread ?

Comment: the problem is not related to timer. And as far I know, Yes, Timer does create a new thread..

Answer (score 2):

Change the _tm_Elapse to this:

```
void _tm_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_tm == (sender as Timer))
        {
            _main.ContentPage.Children.Clear();
            _main.ContentPage.Children.Add(_homeScreen);
        }
    }
```

Edit for answering: 
"I just want it 1 time to fire after 3 sec"

```
void _tm_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_tm == (sender as Timer))
        {
            _tm.Stop();
            _main.ContentPage.Children.Clear();
            _main.ContentPage.Children.Add(_homeScreen);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked, but the problem is that it keeps on going, and every 3 seconds it fires the _tm_Elapsed method. I just want it 1 time to fire after 3 sec.

Answer (score 1):

This is even simpler, and it will only run once per call, the three second timer is built in, and furthermore, it won't disable other program functionalities while it is running:

```
async Task Start()
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    _main.ContentPage.Children.Clear();
    _main.ContentPage.Children.Add(_homeScreen);
}
```